# PSCustomObject array and ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

Background: I have some locations I'd like to have easier access to. I don't want to mklink, because then something may save the path as the link path and fail later.

Proposed solution: Create some PSDrives. Start with a static array of hashtables, so that they can be imported/exported/filtered easily in the future.

Prep-step:

```
# Clear out existing drives, empty error stack
Get-PSDrive -name "*-test-*" | Remove-PSDrive 
$Error.Clear()
```

Failed Solution 1: Create array of hashes with parameter KVPs

```
@(
    @{ Name='hasharray-test-control'; Root='C:\Windows\Temp' },
    @{ Name='hasharray-test-interp-brace'; Root="${ENV:SystemRoot}\Temp" }
) | New-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem
```

Confusing error "The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command ..."

Failed Solution 2: Web-grokking shows that the items have to be PSCustomObject, not a hash

```
@(
    [PSCustomObject]@{ Name='array-test-control'; Root='C:\Windows\Temp' },
    [PSCustomObject]@{ Name='array-test-interp-brace'; Root="${ENV:SystemRoot}\Temp" }
) | New-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem
```

Fails on second item with

```
New-PSDrive : Cannot bind parameter 'Name' to the target. 
Exception setting "Name": 
    "Cannot process argument because the value of argument "value" is null.
```

Failed Solution 3: Ok, Maybe powershell is passing the array as one big blob, make it implicit

```
[PSCustomObject]@{ Name='implicitarray-test-control'; Root='C:\Windows\Temp' },
[PSCustomObject]@{ Name='implicitarray-test-interp-brace'; Root="${ENV:SystemRoot}\Temp" } |
    New-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem
```

Fails on second item with same error

Failed solution 4: Insert intermediate variable

```
$TestDrives = @(
    [PSCustomObject]@{ Name='foreach-test-control'; Root='C:\Windows\Temp' }
    [PSCustomObject]@{ Name='foreach-test-interp-brace'; Root="${ENV:SystemRoot}\Temp" }
) 
$TestDrives | New-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem
```

Fails on second item with same error

Failed Solution 5: Insert a select to extract properties

```
@(
    [PSCustomObject]@{ Name='select-test-control'; Root='C:\Windows\Temp' },
    [PSCustomObject]@{ Name='select-test-interp-brace'; Root="${ENV:SystemRoot}\Temp" }
) | Select Name, Root | New-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem
```

Fails on second item with same error

Failed Solution 6: No? Ok, I'll add a foreach to force each item to resolve

```
$TestDrives = @(
    [PSCustomObject]@{ Name='foreachpipe-test-control'; Root='C:\Windows\Temp' },
    [PSCustomObject]@{ Name='foreachpipe-test-interp-brace'; Root="${ENV:SystemRoot}\Temp" }
) 
$TestDrives | ForEach-Object { $_ } | New-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem
```

Fails on second item with same error

Failed Solution 7: Still No? Fine, Select each property explicitly inside the foreach

```
@(
    [PSCustomObject]@{ Name='foreachselect-test-control'; Root='C:\Windows\Temp' },
    [PSCustomObject]@{ Name='foreachselect-test-interp-brace'; Root="${ENV:SystemRoot}\Temp" }
) | ForEach-Object { $_ | Select Name, Root } | New-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem
```

Fails on second item with same error

And just for good measure, let's try only static values:

```
@(
    [PSCustomObject]@{ Name='foreachstatic-test-control'; Root='C:\Windows\Temp' }
    [PSCustomObject]@{ Name='foreachstatic-test-control-2'; Root='C:\Windows\Temp' }
) | New-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem
```

Fails on second item with same error

Extra notes:

- I tried both with, and without the commas in the array declaration, results are identical
- I also tried the following as the second item with identical results

  - `[PSCustomObject]@{ Name='test-interp'; Root="$HOME\Temp" }`
  - `[PSCustomObject]@{ Name='test-interp-command'; Root="$($HOME)\Temp" }`
  - `[PSCustomObject]@{ Name='test-format'; Root=('{0}\Temp' -f $HOME) }`
  - `[PSCustomObject]@{ Name='test-format-resolve'; Root=$('{0}\Temp' -f $HOME) }`
  - Set `$tRoot` outside hash, and use `[PSCustomObject]@{ Name='test-format-resolve'; Root=$tRoot }`

Working Solution: Wow, I'm speechless... let's force a foreach around everything

```
@(
    [PSCustomObject]@{ Name='foreach-test-control'; Root='C:\Windows\Temp' },
    [PSCustomObject]@{ Name='foreach-test-interp-brace'; Root="${ENV:SystemRoot}\Temp" }
) | ForEach-Object { $_ | New-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem }
```

And now it works, but just feels wrong, since it's already on the pipeline.

And now, the question(s): 
Why do I have to explicitly ForEach-Object in this case instead of being able to use the pipeline, when `New-PSDrive` supports `ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName` for both `Name` and `Root`?

Why does the first item in each array work, while all subsequent items fail?

Comment: +1. That was a lot of trying. And a good question it seems like. I'd leave it to Powershell experts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a problem with the `New-PSDrive` cmdlet, because atm. it only supports a single object at a time. `Remove-PSDrive` does support array-input, which indicates that it should have been included in `New-PSDrive` too (like PS-cmdlets is supposed to work). To verify that it's a bug with the cmdlet, you could run the following command to see how it properly binds the first object's property's, while it cancels at the beginning of the second object.

```
Trace-Command -Expression { 
@(
    [PSCustomObject]@{ Name='array-test-control'; Root='C:\Windows\Temp' },
    [PSCustomObject]@{ Name='array-test-interp-brace'; Root="${ENV:SystemRoot}\Temp" }
) | New-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem
} -Name ParameterBinding -PSHost
```

Pieces of output:

```
#First object
 BIND PIPELINE object to parameters: [New-PSDrive]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     PIPELINE object TYPE = [System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     RESTORING pipeline parameter's original values
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     Parameter [Name] PIPELINE INPUT ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName NO COERCION
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     BIND arg [hasharray-test-interp-brace] to parameter [Name]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         BIND arg [hasharray-test-interp-brace] to param [Name] SUCCESSFUL
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     Parameter [Root] PIPELINE INPUT ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName NO COERCION
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     BIND arg [C:\Windows\Temp] to parameter [Root]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         BIND arg [C:\Windows\Temp] to param [Root] SUCCESSFUL


#Second object
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND PIPELINE object to parameters: [New-PSDrive]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     PIPELINE object TYPE = [System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     RESTORING pipeline parameter's original values
#It now skips right to the result(error) without trying to bind the parameters.
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND PIPELINE object to parameters: [Out-Default]
```

Comment: I've submitted this a bug on connect. If people who can confirm the bug would upvote it, it would help alot. Feedback ID: 810712

Comment: I didn't know about `Trace-Command`, only Set-PSDebug. Also, thanks for opening the Connect item, I would have done so if I had been able to prove the bug as you did.

Answer (score 3):

You are hitting a bug in the implementation of New-PSDrive.

The property setters for the Name/Root/PSDrive parameters aren't written properly to support multiple objects in the pipeline.